# vue constructor not having local state

Tags: vue.js

I have this code:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import s from 'vue-styled-components'
import Test1x from './test1x'

export default Vue.extend({
  name:'test1',
  render(){
    const Div=s.div`
    `
    const test1x1=new Test1x()
    const test1x2=new Test1x()

    const el=
    <Div>
    {test1x1.state.greeting}
    {test1x2.state.greeting}
    <button vOn:click={()=>test1x1.commit('change')}>change</button>
    <button vOn:click={()=>test1x2.commit('change')}>change</button>
    </Div>
    return el
  }
})
```

and `test1x.js` file is as follows:

```
import withStore from './withStore'

export default withStore({
  state: {
    greeting:'hola'
  },
  mutations: {
    change(state){state.greeting='hello'}
  }
})
```

and `withStore.js` file is as follows:

```
import Vue from 'vue'

export default ({ state, mutations }) => {
  return Vue.extend({
    data () {
      return { state }
    },
    methods: {
      commit (mutationName) {
        mutations[mutationName](this.state)
      },
    },
  })
}
```

Given that code, I assume each greeting will be changed by the corresponding button, separately, individually, but not, when I press a button all two greetings change. Anyone knows why? Thank you in advance.

And even more strange is that while at least code presented before is reactive, I mean, greeting change when pressing a button, code below it is not:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import s from 'vue-styled-components'
import withStore from './withStore'

export default Vue.extend({
  name:'test1',
  render(){
    const Div=s.div`
    `
    const Test1x=withStore({
      state: {
        greeting:'hola'
      },
      mutations: {
        change(state){
          state.greeting='hello'
        }
      }
    })

    const test1x1=new Test1x()
    const test1x2=new Test1x()

    const el=
    <Div>
    {test1x1.state.greeting}
    {test1x2.state.greeting}
    <button vOn:click={()=>test1x1.commit('change')}>change</button>
    <button vOn:click={()=>test1x2.commit('change')}>change</button>
    </Div>
    return el
  }
})
```

when pressing button nothing happens, greeting remains with `hola` instead of `hello`. Isn't that strange? Anyone knows why? Thanks again.

**edit**
thanks to @skirtle answer, I solved the issue doing this:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import s from 'vue-styled-components'
import Test1 from './test1/test1'
import Test1x from './test1/test1x'

export default Vue.extend({
  name:'app',
  render(){
    const Div=s.div`
    `

    const test1x1=new Test1x()
    const test1x2=new Test1x()
    //test1x1.commit('init')
    test1x1.state={greeting:'hola'}
    test1x2.state={greeting:'hola'}
    console.log(test1x1.state)

    const el=
    <Div>
    <Test1 test1x={test1x1}/>
    <Test1 test1x={test1x2}/>
    </Div>
    return el
  }
})
```

and `test1.js` being this:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import s from 'vue-styled-components'

export default Vue.extend({
  props:{
    test1x:Object
  },
  name:'test1',
  render(){
    const Div=s.div`
    `

    const el=
    <Div>
    {this.test1x.state.greeting}
    <button vOn:click={()=>this.test1x.commit('change')}>changes</button>
    </Div>
    return el
  }
})
```

and `test1x.js` being this:

```
import withStore from './withStore'

export default withStore({
  state: null,
  mutations: {
    change(state){state.greeting='hello'},
    init(s){s={greeting:'hola'}
  console.log(s)}
  }
})
```

This works. The strange thing now is that if I uncomment `test1x1.commit('init')` I get an infinite loop, don't know why. If I then comment `test1x1.state={greeting:'hola'}` I don't get an infinite loop but I get an error that `cannot read property greeting of null` in `test1.js`. Anyone knows why this is happening? The thing is `test1x1.commit('init')` does not change the value `test1x1.state`, it remains `null`. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Addressing the first problem first.

The problem starts here:

```js
state: {
  greeting:'hola'
},
```

The value of `state` points to a specific object. That object then gets passed around but at no point is a copy taken. The result is that both `test1x1` and `test1x2` will have the same object for `state`.

You can confirm this by adding a bit of console logging:

```js
console.log(test1x1.state === test1x2.state)
```

The way Vuex handles this problem is to allow `state` to be a function, just like `data`:

```js
state () {
  return {
    greeting:'hola'
  }
},
```

Each time the `state` function is invoked it will return a new object.

As you aren't using Vuex you would need to ensure that you call the `state` function at the correct point to generate the relevant object. Something like this:

```js
data () {
  if (typeof state === 'function') {
    state = state()
  }

  return { state }
},
```

So, to your second problem. I'm afraid I don't know what the problem is there. However, I very much doubt that *'when pressing button nothing happens'*. It may not update the message but that isn't the same as *'nothing happens'*. It should be relatively straightforward to add in some console logging at each stage and to establish exactly what does and doesn't happen. Once you've gathered all of that extra information about precisely what *is* happening it should be fairly simple to pinpoint precisely where the disconnect is occurring.

My suspicion would be that you've made some other changes to `withStore` that are causing this new problem. It could also be a file caching problem, so that the code you're running is not the code you think it is. Either way the extra logging should reveal all.

If you need further help with that then please update the question with the extra information gathered via console logging.

**Update:**

This is why the updated code causes an infinite rendering loop:

1. Inside the `render` function there is a call to `test1x1.commit('init')`.
2. Inside `commit` it accesses the property `this.state`. This will add the property `this.state` as a rendering dependency for the component. It doesn't matter what the current value of `this.state` is, it's the property itself that is the dependency, not its current value.
3. On the next line it sets `test1x1.state={greeting:'hola'}`. This changes the value of the `state` property. This is the same `state` that has just been registered as a rendering dependency. As a rendering dependency has now changed the component will be re-added to the rendering queue, even though it hasn't finished the current rendering yet.
4. Eventually Vue will work its way through the rendering queue and get back to this same component. It will again call `render` to try to render the component. The previous steps will all occur again and so the component keeps being rendered over and over.

The bottom line here is that you shouldn't be initialising these data structures within the `render` function in the first place. There are various places you might create them but inside `render` does not appear to be appropriate based on the code you've provided.

Comment: thanks very much master. I will try your solutions. When I have more info I will update the question. Thanks.

Comment: @roggc I have updated my answer based on your latest question update. I fear this question may be turning into a chameleon. I'm happy to help further but please try to ensure that any new additions are within the scope of the original question. Otherwise a new question would be more appropriate.

Comment: ok thanks, @skirtle. you know a lot. is there any place apart from the official doc from Vue where I can learn all these things (registering a dependency, rendering queue, etc)? are all these on the official doc? and last, do you have a hint on why in this case `test1x1.commit('init')` doesn't appear to have effect on `test1x1.state`? thanks very much for your help.

Comment: ok thanks, @skirtle. you know a lot. is there any place apart from the official doc from Vue where I can learn all these things (registering a dependency, rendering queue, etc)? are all these on the official doc? and last, do you have a hint on why in this case `test1x1.commit('init')` doesn't appear to have effect on `test1x1.state`? thanks very much for your help.

Comment: @roggc The official documentation is pretty good. Beyond that the weekly newsletter is a good source of further reading. Going even deeper, reading the Vue source code can be quite enlightening, though it takes a bit of practice to get the hang of it. As for `init`, it just seems to be updating the local identifier `s`. It doesn't do anything to the `state` property. Not really sure why you've gone down this route. I'd have gone with a `state` function approach, just like Vuex.

Comment: skirtle, I have posted a new question `Why this code causes an infinite loop in render function in Vue` in StackOverflow regarding the infinite loop question which I still do not get too much the point why this happens. Do you know React.js? Which do you think is better, React.js or Vue.js? I mean React.js with Hooks not classes. Thanks.